# How to draw "Gantt Chart" on JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, charts, paintcomponent

I am trying to implement CPU scheduling algorithms ... i am using `java swing` (not a runtime design)

This is how my main form looks:
I've designed it by dragging components from swing containers/controls/menus and dropping them on a `JFrame`.

I've a `JPanel` on my main-panel of FCFS tab. I want to draw a 'Gantt Chart' on that panel (as it's shown in picture). I've read so many tutorials and implemented many examples on drawing lines but i don't know how to `@Override` `painComponent()` method in my code, because all the variables and methods are generated automatically (am using NetBeans IDE), and am unable to locate my `JPanel` (on which i want to draw lines).

[image]

I want to draw a "Gantt Chart" like this one. It will be generated automatically when user enters CPU burst for a number of processes and presses "Calculate" button. The current chart will be generated if user enters '10 ms' burst for each process.

[image]

In this picture i've tried to explain the sequence of components, i've added on my JFrame, along with their variable names.

[image]

I'm searching for the solution from last 15 days ... but am stuck in this problem ... please please help me to solve this problem.

Please please please help me...

Comment: @user1803551 ... save where ?

Comment: Never mind, I embedded them.

Comment: @user1803551 ... i've just got enough reputation to post pictures (-:

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is first understanding how Swing uses the MVC pattern, examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513). Just as a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) listens to its [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), a [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) Gantt plot listens to its own `CategoryDataset`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15241250/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696975/230513).

Override `setValueAt()` in your `TableModel` and update your `CategoryDataset` accordingly. Both the `JTable` and Gantt plot will update themselves in response. If required, you can alter the [`GanttRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/GanttRenderer.html) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20extends%20GanttRenderer).

While [debatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/468328/230513), I'd advocate hand coding over a GUI builder at this stage in development? If you go with the builder, limit the scope as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).

Comment: thank you so much for help ... actually my problem is that i've to draw gantt chart using `paint()` method for JFrame .. or `paintComponent()` method for other components ...

Comment: i have not studied MVC yet .. and never used JFreeChart before ... so am not aware of them .. but i seriously need help ... please help me to find solution

Comment: as you can see in first picture .. i've created two tables ... what i did was: i created them on a JPanel using Netbeans GUI ... then in events of my JTextField and Calculate-Button i used `DefaultTableModel` to fill these tables ... i want to do the same for Gantt chart ... i've a JPanel on which i want to draw my chart ... the chart will be generated when user presses the Calculate button .. so i've to write my code in actionPerformed of Calculate button ... but i don't know what to write there .. i don't understand how can i override `paintComponent()` method and use it there

Comment: i've tried making an inner-class which draws on a JPanel .. but i don't understand how to use its object to draw on my specified JPanel .. please help me

Comment: I'd go with MVC in this context. If you don't use [tag:jfreechart], you might be able to get away with letting your `TableModel` update your Gantt view component directly. "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks). Too avoid being closed as too broad, please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses any problem you encounter with your revised approach.