# Removing last three zeros with DecimalFormat

Tags: java, jfreechart, decimalformat

I'm using jfreechart to display axis values in milliseconds but I'd like to show the axis labels in seconds, so I'd use `domainAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new DecimalFormat("???"));`

So what's the syntax to remove last three zeros? e.g.: 1.000, 2.000, 3.000 to 1, 2, 3.

Comment: When the values are `1000, 2000, 3000` and you want to display instead `1, 2, 3` you need to divide them by `1000`. Seems the dot is the thausand separator in your locale. Correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: @SubOptimal Yep, I tried with different locales so I can use dot, coma or remove the thousand separator. The question is how to divide by `1000` using `DecimalFormat` syntax.

Comment: You may be looking for `setDateFormatOverride()`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27696975/230513).

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117522).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529432/java-format-number-in-millions/529476#529476) I managed to divide by `1000` subclassing `NumberFormat`

So final code is simply:

```
private static final NumberFormat THOUSANDS = new NumberFormat() {

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(double number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {

        new DecimalFormat().format(number / 1000D, toAppendTo, pos);

        return toAppendTo;
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        return format((double) number, toAppendTo, pos);
    }

    @Override
    public Number parse(String source, ParsePosition parsePosition) {
        return null;
    }
};
```

And the call:

`domainAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(THOUSANDS);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String label= "1.000"
String slabel= new DecimalFormat("0.####").format(Double.parseDouble(label));
System.out.println(slabel);
```

Comment: Thanks @karthick23, it works using Strings but I don't know why it doesn't in jfreechart. Only the dots disappear :/